# Cannot get Twitter-OAuth-iPhone to work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, twitter, oauth

demo works as expected, no problems. But now I'm trying to integrate it into my project. I use no xib-s, code only:

OAuthTwitterDemoViewController *vc = [[OAuthTwitterDemoViewController alloc] init];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:vc.view];
[vc release];

it compiles and runs with no errors, but the actual OAuthTwitterDemoViewController is never visible. I've also tried it from a custom viewController with [self.view addSubview:vc.view]

What's the secret??

---

**Update:**

OK, here's what I did with NavigationController:

```
    TwitterAuthViewController *vc = [[TwitterAuthViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [vc release];

    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
    [navigationController release];
```

Comment: Have you tried pushing the view controller to a nav controller? Do your other views appear properly?

Comment: That was fast, Ben! Yes, UINavigationController helped a lot - I can see TwitterAuthViewController's view. But now I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS... Will try to investigate the issue. 
Any thoughts why it works from UINavigationController and not as I did it before?..

Comment: BTW, I updated the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problems seems to be that I called `[self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES]` from ModalViewController->NavigationController. That's where Cocoa touch OR Twitter-OAuth-iPhone (I don't really know which one exactly) have a problem. But this is how I need it.

Solution would be, as Ben already said, simply to push SA_OAuthTwitterController like `[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated: YES];`.

The only remaining problem is that SA_OAuthTwitterController internally creates own NavigationController bar, so that now I have 2 navigation bars visible.

Comment: The SA_OAuthTwitterController should be able to be used in Modal form; to get rid of your duplicate nav bars, just send one of your nav controllers a -setNavigationBarHidden: message.